# Why don't the net acceleration of the truck becomes zero after hitting the man?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision, free-body-diagram, laws-of-physics

Imagine, there is a truck of mass 'm' accelerating with an acceleration 'a', this means that the truck definately carries some force 'F'(let). Now, imagine the truck collides with a man standing stationary on the middle of the road. So, the truck will hit the man with force 'F' and due to Newton's third law the man also exerts a force 'F' on the truck, then my question is that, why don't the truck's net force becomes zero, and why it continues accelerating? Kindly explain, where am I going wrong.
Note- there is no external force other than 'F' acting on the system.

Comment: What makes you think the man is able to exert as much force on the truck as the truck's engine is exerting on the road?

Comment: A force is not something that an object carries. objects carry momentum (and energy). Forces applied to a body for a length of time induce changes to the momentum of the body. In particular, for a given momentum transfer $\Delta{P}$ the change in the body's speed will be inversely proportional to its mass. That's why heavier objects change their motion less readily than lighter ones when you push on them.

Comment: @Amit Thanks man, my doubt is clear, your reply really helped me alot.

Comment: @SushantSinha "So, the truck will hit the man with force 'F' "  By  F  do you mean the force that was causing the truck to accelerate?

Comment: It’s not clear if the force causing the acceleration of the truck was still being applied during the collision

Comment: @BobD Yes, by 'F' I mean the force which causing the truck to accelerate. My question is like -> after the collision the truck collides with the man and because truck is moving due to 'F' force then after colliding it exerts 'F' force on the man too (since while in motion it is moving due to 'F', so it is carrying 'F' force) and due to equal and opposite reaction the man exerts 'F' on truck, then doesn't the F by man and F by which the truck is traveling is same in magnitude, so they cancel out each other?

Comment: @SushantSinha An action reaction pair ([N3L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Third)) is a pair of forces where each operate on a *different* body. How would they cancel then?

Comment: @Amit I know that action reaction is acts on pair on different bodies, my question was that, if the truck is accelerating, then it must have some force 'F'(since truck has some mass and it is accelerating, this mean it must have some force) and when it hits the man, so doesn't it hits the man with same force 'F' or not (I'm confused at this point), and if truck hits man with 'F' then the man also exerts 'F' force on truck( action-reaction). Now, the truck previously having a force F that's why it is accelerating and after hitting the man, the man exerts a force -F on truck. Now net force is 0.

Comment: @SushantSinha Again you're saying "It must have a force" which doesn't make sense. I pointed out earlier, an object doesn't carry a force. But okay if you mean the truck *exerts* a force on the person, and from Newton 3rd law we know the person is also exerting the same force back on the truck. So? Stand right next to a wall, facing it. Push on it hard. Who is moving back, you or the wall? You're both exerting an equal and opposite force on each other, but only one of you is changing its motion (assuming it's not a flimsy wall ;-)). Why?

Comment: Hmm, I understood your point, but I am just explaining my question again, so that I got some examples, but the point that "the body doesn't carry any force and rather it carries momentum" is now clear to me.

Comment: @SushantSinha now I understand your question. Considering posting an answer

Comment: @SushantSinha Oops! Too late. They closed you question.

Comment: @BobD No problem, now, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This misconception is the same as when you step on an ant, the force your feet exerts will also be exerted by the ant on your feet and thus you would not be able to "deform it".
The thing you are overlooking is that there is a limit to how much force the ant's body or any body can withstand and exert a opposite force before deforming and in cases where this external force exceeds the force the body can withstand, like the example you stated above, the opposing force is reduced by almost a negligible regarding force , approximately equal to the body's net "withstand able" force.

Comment: I don't believe that the ability to withstand a force without deformation (i.e., a rigid body) has relevance to the question.   Conservation of momentum applies without regard to the structure of the objects.   The man will be accelerated away from the truck no matter what.    The OP's question seems related to the question of how motion is possible at all given Newton's third law.

Comment: But don't you think that when a force is applied on an object , it should either oppose the force with the same magnitude , or "succumb" under the influence of the force and either get deformed ( as in the case of ant) and accelerate until it collides with a mass which can oppose the force?